# Making math operations with MySQL table data (JAVA)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Does anyone know which MySQL commands I can use to do this?

[image: TABLE]

I have 2 INT columns **precio** (price) and **cant** (quantity) and I want to multiply these two tables. 
Example:
 10 * 8 = 80 
         10 * 6 = 60 
and so on, then I want to make a sum with all the results of the operations and print the total.

Comment: Please **learn SQL**. This site is not a teaching site, nor a do-the-work-for-me site. Do some research too, because your question has all the right keywords: `*` multiply operator, `SUM()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the two columns and `sum` them:

```
SELECT SUM(precio * cant)
FROM   mytable
```